# SQL Server 2008 R2 folder missing in system

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, rebuild

During rebuilding `master` database in SQL Server, I tried the steps mentioned int he link below:

[link](http://mssqltrek.com/2011/08/20/how-to-rebuild-master-database-aka-rebuilding-sql-server-2008r2/)

But I am getting an error

> Error code: 2 error

so as mentioned there and other sources I want to change my command prompt path from:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Release
```

to the path:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2008R2
```

But I don't have this folder `SQLServer2008R2` on my PC.

Comment: Grab the folder from a different server or the install CD.

Comment: Not sure why you need that directory, if you are just restoring the master database, you need single user mode.